# How to trigger a lambda function when a file is downloaded from a s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, eventtrigger

I am aware of triggering when a file is uploaded into a bucket. But how do we trigger a lambda function when a file is downloaded from a s3 bucket.
I have been trying using server logs and cloud watch but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I do not think that is possible in general, you could *try* to use [S3 object lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-s3-object-lambda-use-your-code-to-process-data-as-it-is-being-retrieved-from-s3/) for that. There are no cloudwatch notifications for that, there are cloudtrail entries if you enable them (which might be very pricey).

Comment: If you have an application that downloads an Object from Amazon S3, you can manually invoke the Lambda function via the Lambda SDK.

Comment: but what if we need to trigger when an object is moved from one bucket to another ( and we cannot access the destination bucket ie we only have access to the source bucket)...??

Comment: that is generally nothing that you can / should worry / think about. *Why* does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently S3 dosen't support read events.

However, their can be 2 approaches to solve the issue.

1. Use cloudTrail to track api call which reads S3 object and create an alarm on event which in turn triggers the lambda.

S3 --> CloudTrail (Read Call) --> CloudWatch Event --> Lambda

or otherwise

2. Just don't give access to bucket directly and control the downloads via lambda itself.

Comment: thank you I think the second approach would be cheap and effective :)

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. AWS offers S3 Object Lambda exactly for this purpose. Is there a reason to not use it?